# How to hide text behind image

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have my web template (made in Photoshop) ready and set to upload to server; however, if user hides/disables images, website will be blank because all the text is on the images.

I have created the CSS layout and want to make a text version of the website, but how do I achieve this without having the text overlap the image?? I want the user to still see a text version of the website in case they disable the images on their browser.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="main_divs_container">
    <div id="left_div"><img src="images/left_div.jpg" width="249" height="622" alt=""></div>
    <div id="index_middle_div"><img src="images/index_middle_div.jpg" width="488" height="622" alt=""></div>
    <div id="right_div"><img src="images/right_div.jpg" width="253" height="622" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the text in your `alt=` tag.

That should show the text when images are blocked.
(That's pretty much the purpose of the alt tag, to represent content when a image is inaccessible, one way or another)

It won't be pretty when it contains a load of text, though, if it renders at all.
The best option would be to use the images (without text) as background, and add the text on top of it through HTML.

Comment: So what you're saying is I would have to modify the images on photoshop in such a way that I would leave the text portion blank so that I could add whatever text through HTML?

Comment: @user482520: That would be the best choice, yes.
That means that, if the images don't load, the text still will, and you'll have more control over the text than when it's in the `alt` tag. (CSS and all that)

Comment: No problem!
Please consider marking this as the answer, if you wish ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create one html version of website. In photoshop we create template just for reference or client review (just for visual purpose.) . that is not the final output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS Image Replacement (http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) to have text and images at the sime time in Your HTML (text not visible).

Than You have to write CSS styles, one that will show the images and hides the text, and second that will do the oposit.

Next just apply right style using JS to detect if user has blocked images or not :)